# JProbe Snapshots and setting recodring level options

Tags: java, profiling, jprobe

I am trying to profile my java application with JProbe.

I am little confused with Snapshots and 'Set Recording Level' options. I am not able to understand the relation between them.

Can somebody please take pain to explain me or point to any online articles which can clarify my confusion.

Thank you very much,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Set Recording Level' options define what data will be recorded in the snapshot you are taking. Below are the details

**Data Recording Off:**  You are at the initial stage of your investigation,
when you do not know what is leaking or why. This is often enough to at least start your investigation.

**Record Allocations For All Instances:** You want to record only the allocation times of instances, which are displayed in the Instance Detail view. The Call Traces and Merged
Allocation Points views are not available in this case, as no trace data is collected.

**Record Allocations and Stack Traces For All Instances:** You want to record allocation times, as well as stack traces. You can use the Call Traces and Merged Allocation Points views to analyze “where instances came from”.

**Record Allocations, Stack Traces, and Garbage Data For All Instances:** You want to find what methods are allocating shortlived objects in your program, or where these
objects were allocated (that is, you want to use the Call Traces or Merged Allocation Points views while investigating by Dead Count or Dead Memory).
***Note:***  This may have a severe performance and memory impact.

**Record Data as Specified in the Table Below:** You know the class or classes of objects that you need to track. This option can be particularly useful with large programs where collecting detailed trace or garbage data for all instances is slow and uses a
lot of memory.